# Error executing stored procedure with datatable parameter in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to add or update a collection of object executed in c#, but not sure why it isn't executing correctly in c# while it works fine in sql.

I'm not sure how generate some useful error message to help with debugging either.

Any tip or pointer to guide me to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Here's the sample code:

SQL script:

```
CREATE TYPE CodeList
AS TABLE
(
    Code varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    GeneratedDate date NULL
);
GO

PRINT 'Created CodeList Type';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrUpdateCodes
    @List AS CodeList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE dbo.Code AS tgt
    USING @List AS src
    ON tgt.Code = src.Code
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Name = src.Name, GeneratedDate = src.GeneratedDate
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Code, Name, GeneratedDate) VALUES (src.Code, src.Name, src.GeneratedDate);
END
GO

PRINT 'Created AddOrUpdateCodes Stored Procedure';
GO

DECLARE @List AS CodeList;

INSERT INTO @List (Code, Name, GeneratedDate) VALUES ('SQLTEST', 'SQLTEST', '2018-07-30')

EXEC AddOrUpdateCodes @List
GO

SELECT * FROM Symbol;
```

C# Code:

```
public int AddOrUpdateCodes(List<Code> codes)
{
    using (var entity = new CodeEntities())
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable("CodeList");
        using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(codes, "Code", "Name", "GeneratedDate"))
        {
            dataTable.Load(reader);
        }

        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@List", dataTable);
        sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        sqlParameter.TypeName = "dbo.CodeList";
        var result = entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("AddOrUpdateCodes",
            sqlParameter);
        entity.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @HoneyBadger raises a great point - in the future, be sure to include the exact error message you get.  See [ask] and [mcve] for more details.

Comment: @Brian Yah part of my problem was I didn't get any error messages or wasn't sure how I can capture one as I mention in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() method helps to executes the given DDL/DML command against the database. Try using this line passing SqlParameters:

```
var result = entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("AddOrUpdateCodes @List",
    sqlParameter);
    entity.SaveChanges();
        return result;
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the careless mistake I made there.